# Create Codable Struct with multiple child element from loop

Tags: swift

I have a codable struct that I will be using to generate JSON for an API call. The element slide.slideData.elText needs to carry multiple instances of itself that will be generated by a loop. Although I can populate the values for a single instance of elText I'm struggling to find how I can add multiple instances of this element. SlideData.elText needs to be an array of elText instances basically rather than just one instance. The data will look something like this:

Loop 1:
content: "loop 1 content"
color: "loop 1 color"

Loop 2:
content: "loop 2 content"
color: "loop 2 color"

Loop 3:
content: "loop 3 content"
color: "loop 3 color"

etc. This is the current Struct:

```
struct ApiSlideData: Codable {

    let slide: [Slide]

    struct Slide : Codable {
        let id: Int
        let createdById: Int
        let memberId: Int
        let slideTitle: String
        let productType: String
        let slideType: String
        let slideData: [SlideData]
    }

    struct SlideData: Codable {
        let elText: [ElText]
    }

    struct ElText : Codable {
        let content: String
        let color: String
     }

}
```

And this is how I am currently populating the data:

```
let elText = ApiSlideData.ElText(
    content: "loop 1 content",
    color: "loop 1 color"
)

let slideData = ApiSlideData.SlideData(
    elText: [elText]
)

let slide = ApiSlideData.Slide(
    id: 1,
    createdById: 102,
    memberId: 1,
    slideTitle: "test title",
    productType: "bc",
    slideType: "company-profile",
    slideData: [slideData]
    )

let apiSlide = ApiSlideData(slide: [slide])

print("---------------------------------")
print("apiSlide: \(apiSlide)")
```

Which results in this output:

```
apiSlide: ApiSlideData(slide: [My_app.ApiSlideData.Slide(id: 1, createdById: 102, 
memberId: 1, slideTitle: "test title", productType: "bc", slideType: "company-profile", 
slideData: [My_app.ApiSlideData.SlideData(elText: 
[My_app.ApiSlideData.ElText(content: "loop 1 content", color: "loop 1 color")])])])
```

I need to end up with something like this:

```
apiSlide: ApiSlideData(slide: [My_app.ApiSlideData.Slide(id: 1, createdById: 102, 
memberId: 1, slideTitle: "test title", productType: "bc", slideType: "company-profile", 
slideData: [My_app.ApiSlideData.SlideData(elText: 
[My_app.ApiSlideData.ElText[
(content: "loop 1 content", color: "loop 1 color"),
(content: "loop 2 content", color: "loop 2 color"),
(content: "loop 3 content", color: "loop 2 color")
]
])])])
```

The JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
    "slide": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_by_id": 102,
            "member_id": 1,
            "slide_title": "TITLE TEXT",
            "product_type": "bc",
            "slide_type": "type-text",
            "slide_data": {
                "el_text": [
                    {
                        "content": "TEXT CONTENT",
                        "color": "48a7c3",
                        "element_width": 220,
                        "element_height": 90,
                        "element_center_x": 97.5,
                        "element_center_y": 96.0,
                        "element_angle": 2.16,
                        "stack_layer": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "content": "TEXT CONTENT 2",
                        "color": "000000",
                        "element_width": 220,
                        "element_height": 90,
                        "element_center_x": 97.5,
                        "element_center_y": 96.0,
                        "element_angle": 2.16,
                        "stack_layer": 2
                    },
                ],
                "el_image": [
                    {
                        "content": 
                       "2757439c3f424a7f99fbdc04e306d150a4752e8b.png",
                        "element_width": 220,
                        "element_height": 90,
                        "element_center_x": 97.5,
                        "element_center_y": 96.0,
                        "element_angle": 2.16,
                        "stack_layer": 3
                    }
                ],
                "el_shape": [
                    {
                        "type": "rect",
                        "color": "48a7c3",
                        "element_width": 220,
                        "element_height": 90,
                        "element_center_x": 97.5,
                        "element_center_y": 96.0,
                        "element_angle": 2.16,
                        "stack_layer": 4
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Show your JSON structure.

Comment: It depends on how your data is structured containing the content and colors. I think you can use map or reduce to transform your data to ElText objects and put them into your slideData as you are already doing? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map

Comment: @Frankenstein - I've posted the basic structure in case it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following structure:

```swift
struct TopLevel: Codable {
    let slide: [Slide]
}

struct Slide: Codable {
    let id, createdByID, memberID: Int
    let slideTitle, productType, slideType: String
    let slideData: SlideData

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case createdByID = "created_by_id"
        case memberID    = "member_id"
        case slideTitle  = "slide_title"
        case productType = "product_type"
        case slideType   = "slide_type"
        case slideData   = "slide_data"
    }
}

struct SlideData: Codable {
    let elText, elImage, elShape: [El]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case elText  = "el_text"
        case elImage = "el_image"
        case elShape = "el_shape"
    }
}

struct El: Codable {
    let content: String?
    let elementWidth, elementHeight: Int
    let elementCenterX, elementCenterY, elementAngle: Double
    let stackLayer: Int
    let type, color: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case content
        case elementWidth   = "element_width"
        case elementHeight  = "element_height"
        case elementCenterX = "element_center_x"
        case elementCenterY = "element_center_y"
        case elementAngle   = "element_angle"
        case stackLayer     = "stack_layer"
        case type, color
    }
}
```

And create the `SlideData struct` variable instead of looping through your content.

Comment: Hi @Frankenstein - Thanks this a great help in terms of the structure of the struct but I still don't understand how I can add the two instances of the "el_text" element into the struct. I am not populating the struct from the JSON. I need to populate it from live data in the app and then use the struct to encode it to JSON. I have it working via your suggestion for a single instance of each of the "slide_data" elements ("el_text", "el_image", "el_shape") but I need to be able to add multiple instances of each of these as shown for "el_text" in the JSON example.

Answer (score 0):

After some jiggery-pokery I managed to work it out. Using the new struct the way to add multiple instances of the el_text element is as follows (code shows the manual creation of the full struct and encodes as expected):

```
var elTextTest: [ApiSlideData.ElText] = []

    let elText = ApiSlideData.ElText(
        content: "test content",
        color: "ffccff",
        fontStyle: "",
        fontWeight: "",
        fontSize:  20,
        textAlignment: "",
        elementWidth: 200,
        elementHeight: 100,
        elementCenterX: 180,
        elementCenterY: 90,
        elementAngle: -0.432,
        stackLayer: 1
    )

    let elText2 = ApiSlideData.ElText(
        content: "test again",
        color: "ccffcc",
        fontStyle: "",
        fontWeight: "",
        fontSize:  20,
        textAlignment: "",
        elementWidth: 200,
        elementHeight: 100,
        elementCenterX: 180,
        elementCenterY: 90,
        elementAngle: -0.432,
        stackLayer: 1
    )

    elTextTest.append(contentsOf: [elText])
    elTextTest.append(contentsOf: [elText2])

    let elImage = ApiSlideData.El(
        content: "image-url",
        elementWidth: 200,
        elementHeight: 100,
        elementCenterX: 180,
        elementCenterY: 90,
        elementAngle: -0.432,
        stackLayer: 1,
        type: "",
        color: ""
    )

    let elShape = ApiSlideData.El(
        content: "",
        elementWidth: 200,
        elementHeight: 100,
        elementCenterX: 180,
        elementCenterY: 90,
        elementAngle: -0.432,
        stackLayer: 1,
        type: "rect",
        color: "ffccff"
    )

    let slideData = ApiSlideData.SlideData(
        elText: elTextTest,
        elImage: [elImage],
        elShape: [elShape]
    )

    let slide = ApiSlideData.Slide(
        createdOn: "2020-03-08 20:13:11.779738+00",
        updatedOn: "2020-03-08 20:13:11.779738+00",
        id: 1,
        createdById: 102,
        memberId: 1,
        slideTitle: "test title",
        productType: "bc",
        slideType: "type-1",
        slideData: slideData
        )

    let apiSlide = ApiSlideData(slide: [slide])
```